# Is it possible to extract this type in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

This code doesn't work but i'm wondering if there's a way to type the method argument in such a way that is based on the value provided by the svc argument?

```
interface Registry {
  "a": {
    get: () => {},
  },
  "b": {
    get: () => {},
    delete: () => {},
  }
}

function callService(svc: keyof Registry, method: keyof Registry[svc]) {} // method type here is wrong

// expected compile errors
callService("a", "get") // ok
callService("b", "get") // ok
callService("b", "delete") // ok
callService("a", "delete") // compile error
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes! It's possible using generics

```
function callService<T extends keyof Registry>( // Define a generic named T for this function.
   svc: T, // The generic will take this value.
   method: keyof Registry[T] // We can use the generic for other typings.
) {}
```

[image]
[Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=14&ssc=5&pln=12&pc=5#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEoQObAM5igT2QG8AoZZAIjgoC5izzkMIw6AKASmQF4A+YgL4AaBsIYUARrXqMmLdlz6CRsgCYQANiwgKe-ImPICSxkjACuIBGGAB7EMgRwNGgMrQAbsCQAeACrIEAAekCCq2MgA1hD4tjBomDh4+LxsyAD06cgAIhAwoChwciDQ3sggcAC2EKrIATC2UMhgABY4yBZWNvYAdAzk2B4IdH5CGVl+LSjMJVBlAO7ALs1w0c1tER7O5hB9stWttqp00bHx6Fi4BADafgC648gA6ihODubYKK3TELNlDU1bN8mmB8AAHUAYbB9LgGEgkTKBIJgiDWGqOWyVCFaQJQKCNbAkJwudxQLxINhUChjCjMMAULiI2yRInONyebwQSlSGl0hmPZmskkcimSamUdRaSD8pks4nssmcynUGmS7QyrIITHYlDQfFQEhAA)